# d3js: Creating multiple radio buttons

Tags: javascript, d3.js, radio-button

I'm trying to create two radio buttons using d3, however I seem to be having some issues. I can create and label both, however they don't recognize that the other one has been created. For example, if the `OR` button is selected and I select the `AND` button, the `OR` button won't unselect.

I was able to recreate [my problem in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bddavidson/v1fwmvnt/) and the code is below:

```
var body = d3.select("body")

var form = body.append('form');

form.append('input')
    .attr('type', 'radio')
    .attr('value', 'Or')
    .on('click', function () {
        //Do something
    });

form.append('label')
    .html('OR');

form.append('input')
    .attr('type', 'radio')
    .attr('value', 'And')
    .on('click', function () {
        //Do something
    });

form.append('label')
    .html('AND');
```

Comment: You need to give both a "name" attribute with the same value, which is how the browser knows that they're part of the same group.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Put it in an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by assigning both radio buttons a name.

See the [updated fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/bddavidson/v1fwmvnt/)

```
var body = d3.select("body")

var form = body.append('form');

form.append('input')
    .attr('type', 'radio')
    .attr('value', 'Or')
    .attr('name', 'toggle')
    .on('click', function () {
        //Do something
    });

form.append('label')
    .html('OR');

form.append('input')
    .attr('type', 'radio')
    .attr('value', 'And')
    .attr('name', 'toggle')
    .on('click', function () {
        //Do something
    });

form.append('label')
    .html('AND');
```